# Detecting Browser user agent forgery

Tags: http, security, https, http-headers

While it is important that people should use approved browsers downloaded from their legitimate sites to use them, is there any way for the server to detect if someone is spoofing the browser (user agent)?

My question is in particular reference to security. What if someone creates a browser (user agent) and does not respect some contracts (for example, Same origin policy of cookies) to exploit vulnerabilities there? This illegitimate browser can claim that it is a genuine user agent by populating the `User-Agent` header with standard values used in Firefox or Chrome.

Is there any way at the server side to detect if the user is using spoofed user agent so that the server can take counter measures if needed? Or is this the absolute responsibility of the individual using the browser to use approved browsers only (servers have no way to detect it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers are just high level user interfaces to HTTP. Prior to the introduction of various security methods there was not much in place to prevent such attacks. Nowadays browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) have restrictions and abide by certain rules/contracts (in order to work properly).

One can spoof(send) anything with a HTTP client (a very lean
"browser") such as CURL.

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" http://blah.nonexistent.tld
```

(The default curl header is something like User-Agent: curl/7.16.3)

A server could restrict or detect uncommon User-Agents to prevent scraping or scanning, but the user agent is nothing but a "name" and could just be changed to a common one as done above.

The security methods (**contracts**) that have been added such as [Same Origin Resource Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) / [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) / [HTTP Only](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) are there to protect the client (browser) and server. They must be implemented by both in order to function properly(securely) to protect against an attack as mentioned. If the client and the server don't properly use the **contracts** agreed upon, then cookies could be exfiltrated (A modern browser is designed to fail fast and would still prevent this).

If you meant that you were to create your own browser set its User-Agent as Chrome, ignore contracts in place by properly configured servers then they might ignore you. What user cookies would you steal from a "custom" browser, that few people may use?

Comment: Got it, that is what I thought; but was unsure if I was thinking it correctly. Just wanted to know if server the server could somehow detect if I am spoofing. It seems that the answer is NO. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SRaj - Servers can still detect spoofing. If you ask the question, can server detect spoofing using "only" user-agents, then the answer is No. But server can implement something additional to user-agents and can detect spoofing. I would recommend reading about Google Picasso Project. https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45581.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Browsers run different JS engines and respond differently, so any slightly sophisticated anti-useragent forgery detection will work.

Some examples:

```
Chrome:

Math.hypot(-24.42, -50.519999999999925) -> 56.1124478168614
window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame !== undefined -> true
window.mozInnerScreenX !== undefined -> false
window.PERSISTENT !== undefined -> true
window.chrome !== undefined -> true
window.InstallTrigger !== undefined -> false


Firefox:

Math.hypot(-24.42, -50.519999999999925) -> 56.11244781686139
window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame !== undefined -> false
window.mozInnerScreenX !== undefined -> true
window.PERSISTENT !== undefined -> false
window.chrome !== undefined -> false
window.InstallTrigger !== undefined -> true
```

See also: https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs